# Visualizing a Likert scale in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, likert

```
df10_data <- df_na  %>%
  select(Q10_1, Q10_2, Q10_3, Q10_4, Q10_5, Q10_6)

df10_factor <- df10_d %>% mutate_all(str_trim)%>% mutate_if(is.character,as.factor)

levels(df10_factor$Q10_1) <- c(levels(df10_factor$Q10_1), "Intend to use on my farm")
levels(df10_factor$Q10_3) <- c(levels(df10_factor$Q10_3), "Intend to use on my farm")
levels(df10_factor$Q10_4) <- c(levels(df10_factor$Q10_4), "Intend to use on my farm")
levels(df10_factor$Q10_5) <- c(levels(df10_factor$Q10_5), "Intend to use on my farm")


df10_f <- df10_factor %>%   mutate(Q10_1 = fct_relevel(Q10_1,"Not familiar with","No interest in using on my farm","Interested in using, but there is a barrier","Intend to use on my farm","Currently using on my farm", "Did not Answer"), Q10_2= fct_relevel(Q10_2,"Not familiar with","No interest in using on my farm","Interested in using, but there is a barrier","Intend to use on my farm","Currently using on my farm", "Did not Answer"), Q10_3= fct_relevel(Q10_3,"Not familiar with","No interest in using on my farm","Interested in using, but there is a barrier","Intend to use on my farm","Currently using on my farm", "Did not Answer"), Q10_4= fct_relevel(Q10_4,"Not familiar with","No interest in using on my farm","Interested in using, but there is a barrier","Intend to use on my farm","Currently using on my farm", "Did not Answer"), Q10_5= fct_relevel(Q10_5,"Not familiar with","No interest in using on my farm","Interested in using, but there is a barrier","Intend to use on my farm","Currently using on my farm", "Did not Answer"), Q10_6= fct_relevel(Q10_6,"Not familiar with","No interest in using on my farm","Interested in using, but there is a barrier","Intend to use on my farm","Currently using on my farm", "Did not Answer"))

df100 <- as.data.frame(df10_f)

df1000 <- df100 %>% plyr::rename(c("Q10_1"="Grazing Land Management (Rotational Grazing)","Q10_2"="Livestock Fencing to protect streams and sensitive areas","Q10_3"="Alternative Water Supply.","Q10_4"="Feedlot Water Diversion System","Q10_5"="Feedlot Relocation","Q10_6"="Streambank Stabilization")) %>% 
  likert()
plot(df1000, wrap = 20, text.size = 3, ordered = TRUE) +
  ggtitle(title) +
  labs(title = "Life Stock Owners' Experience with Conservation Practices", y = "") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = NULL)) +
  theme_ipsum_rc() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10), axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 0, size=8))`
```

Plot:
[image]

I am trying to create a likert stacked bar chart but it does not show the percentages on the axis properly. Please help me with this

I am guessing that maybe there are too many elements parameters that are causing this issue. I am pretty new to R. I could not figure this out on my own. Also please suggest any elegant way of adding a level to all columns of a data frame and re-leveling the levels when the levels are the same for all columns of data frame.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You maximize your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  may help.